# OnClick on button with title

Tags: javascript, redirect, button, onclick

I need when click in a button with `title = "Like"` redirect to other page in JavaScript:

```
<button class="button-like button button-medium button-responsive" aria-describedby="tooltip-94" tabindex="0" title="Like">Like</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of `$('button[title="Like"]')` selector and call onclick on it.

```
$(function(){

  $('button[title="Like"]').on('click', function(){
    window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com'
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Call a javascript function onclick of button  and inside that javascript function  use

window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";